# What should I use as piece of code to run PDFMiner 3k?

Tags: python, hash, nlp, pypi, pdfminer

I want to use PDFMiner 3k, I'm using python 3.3.3 on windows, I don't know what instructions to write to use the PFDMiner 3k, I've tried many codes and still doesn't work, some of them were for the PDFMiner (python 2.7), for example I've tried the next code :

```
import nltk

from io import StringIO

from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter

from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter

from pdfminer.layout import LAParams

from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
```

Note that I've put the script's file in a directory containing the directory of the PDFMiner 3k. The later is named pdfminer.

I get the next error :

```
 ImportError: No module named 'pdfminer.pdfminer'; pdfminer is not a package
```

Any suggestions?, i need help guys.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell, but it sounds like your problem is that you didn't install PDFMiner3k, you just unzipped it into the same directory as your data.

Don't do that. A few packages work that way, but most don't.

Also, `PDFMiner3k` requires some packages that don't come with Python, like `ply`. If you don't have them, it's not going to work.

The right way to install packages is almost always to use [`pip`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html).

In fact, you don't even have to download it; just `pip install PDFMiner3k`, and `pip` will search for the latest version, and the latest versions of everything it requires, and install them all for you.

---

Of course you're also going to need to install NLTK if you want `nltk` to work. But you can probably guess the command for that.

There are some packages that need a C compiler to build. While there should be binary wheels for most of these so `pip install spam` still works, some packages aren't totally up to date. So, if you get errors about compilers or vcvarsall or similar, check out [Christoph Gohlke's site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/); he has wheels for packages that don't make their own.

Comment: hi, all what u said @abarnert was right i've just unzipped PDFMiner3k. So i've tried what u recommanded, i've downloaded pip,  and i've started downloading PDFMiner3k using the commands that u suggested(in the cmd). My 1st attempt of downloading stopped at 12%.                                                                     I got this error after the sentence "Collecting PDFMiner3k":             Using cached PDFMiner3k-1.3.0.tar.gz (with the white color)                                                             Hash of the package...(with the red color). can u help me @abarnert!!.

Comment: @zouarislam: Occasionally PyPI (the server pip talks to) has transient network problems. If it's still failing now, google for "pip PyPI mirror" to see the current list of mirrors and how to use them with pip.

Comment: Or, since you've already downloaded it: pip can usually install from a tarball/zip (`pip install ./spam.tar.gz`), and it can always install from a pristine unzipped directory (cd into it, then `pip install .`).